# How to pass String to AsyncTask doInBackground , and return ArrayList<String> to onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask

How to pass String to doInBackground and return ArrayList to  onPostExecute.
What i want want to pass html URL to Asyntask  doInBackground and in onPostExecute i want to do things with UI.

I want to try something like this

```
    new calc_stanica().execute("where we send URL as String");//
```

and AsynTask:

```
public class calc_stanica extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {           

    }

    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... passing) {    

        // here i want to from  URL String pars data to ArrayList<String>          

        return ArrayList<String>;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {

    //    do with ArrayList<String>         

    }
}
```

Comment: Is there something that is not working ? What is your question ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class calc_stanica extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {           

    }

    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... passing) {    
String URLStr=passing[0];//as you are passing 1 url only so this will work for u    
ArrayList<String> arraylist=new ArrayList<String>();
        // here u do the things u wana do and add the  String data to ArrayList<String>  and return         

        return arraylist;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {

    //    do with ArrayList<String>         

    }
}
```

Comment: Why when i do like that i have empty Array in onPostExecute?

Comment: Can you share the code what you are doing. If you are not adding any string data  in the arraylist so only u might have got it empty